# Unable to resolve "./aws-exports" from "App.js"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I have been building an app with `awsamplify` for quite some time now. Today I descided to run some test and when I did

```
npm run start-web
```

Everythin worked fine. Now I went on to run mobile test with the use of Expo and ran

```
npm run ios & npm run android
```

which both returned the following errors.

```
Unable to resolve "./aws-exports" from "App.js"

Building JavaScript bundle: error
```

my problem is similar to the one below just its `amplify` and not `awsmobile`

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/669

Deos anyone know what I can do to resolve this?

Thanks alot!

I jsut removed some unused imports and the error changed to this

```
Unable to resolve "@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style.css" from "node_modules\aws-amplify-react\dist\Amplify-UI\Amplify-UI-Components-React.js"
```

Comment: Did you run `amplify init` and `amplify push`?

Comment: yes I did run both

Comment: Are you able to find `aws-exports.js` from your project?

Comment: actually didn't check since the web part worked i assumed it must be there let me check

Comment: its listed in the .gitignorefile but apart from that it isn't

Comment: Now I have no clue. Maybe make sure you run the latest version of amplify-cli. amplify push should generate the aws-exports.js

Comment: I just removed some unused exports and the error changed to                                                       Unable to resolve "@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style.css" from "node_modules\aws-amplify-react\dist\Amplify-UI\Amplify-UI-Components-React.js"

Comment: maybe not do extra change before resolving the 1st issue?

Comment: yeah you are right

Answer (score 16):

Barely mentioned in the AWS docs:

- For setting up a local dev folder, from an existing amplify repo, use an `amplify env pull`,

  It will "pull" the `./aws-exports.js` from the server, the latest one that was pushed there,
  similar to git push and git pull but for the amplify env
- It's true that an amplify push will create the `./aws-exports.js` file,
  but it will also "push" it to the server, overwriting whatever is there.
- `amplify status` is also a handy command, similar to git status

Answer (score 1):

I ran amplify env pull
and then found it in the ./src/aws-exports.js

not sure if the pull did it, or if it was always there but this is for an existing expo project

Answer (score 0):

Confing your projects, using terminal go to the main folder `and amplify init` to config your project

```
amplify init

Do you to use an existing environment? (Y/n) Y

Choose the environment you would like to use: dev

Choose your default editor: Visual Studio Code

Choose the type of app you're building: javascript

What javascript framework you're using: ionic

Source Directory Path: src

Distribution Directory Path: www

Build Command: npm run-script build

Do you want to use an AWS profile? Y

Please choose the profile you want to use: select your personal IAM profile
```